how to watch changes of a variable based on watched state of another variable
i am using vue3 with options api
As shown in the code posted below, i want to watch value.processAPIPathToTIFF, but calling property processAPIPathToTIFF is contigent upon the mapFeaturesReaders.listenToWSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponse, i mean if the latter function is not initialized then
value.processAPIPathToTIFF can not be invoked, so value.processAPIPathToTIFF is reliant on the value of mapFeaturesReaders.listenToWSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponse.
to solve this issue, i created the code shown below, but at run time, despite mapFeaturesReaders.listenToWSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponse is initialized and has value, the body of the if-statement in the below code does not get exectued.
what i am trying to achieve is, to be able to watch changes in processAPIPathToTIFF based on the watched state of listenToWSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponse
what i am doing wrong and how to fix it please
note
mapFeaturesReaders.listenToWSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponse() returns an object of type Ref
code:
this.$watch(() => mapFeaturesReaders.listenToWSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponse(), (newVal, oldVal) => {
    if (newVal && newVal.value) {
        this.wsFetchNDVIsTIFFResponseProcessAPIPathToTIFF = newVal.value.processAPIPathToTIFF;
    }
})


Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , all relevant code needs to be presented in the question, the problem depends on how it works exactly

@EstusFlask thanks for your comment, so do you think that the code provided in my question should work!

In order to answer your question we need to understand which parts of your code are reactive. And it's not clear from what you posted so far. You should at least show the contents of mapFeaturesReaders.

@Amr This totally depends on the implementation of listenToWSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponse(), which isn't shown. Based on the convoluted nature of classes presented in previous question, it can be expected that something goes wrong with reactivity

@tao please read the note i added to the question

If listenToWSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponse() returns a Ref, you only need to get it once: this.$watch(mapFeaturesReaders.listenToWSFetchNDVIsTIFFResponse(), functionToRunWhenRefValueChanges()). Note the first argument (newValue) will be the value, not the Ref.

I'd also ask why expose/export a function which returns a ref instead of exporting/exposing the ref itself? Most likely, that's unnecessary.
